# Where Do the Handsignals the SGC Uses Come From?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In *Stargate: SG1* there are many times Jack O'Neill uses handsignals to communicate with his team members.  When I've searched, I've seen a number of different languages using hand signals, but I've never used them or seen much on them before.

Where are the signals the SGC uses from?  Is there a place online where I can see what they are?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While SG-1 is Air Force, they probably use the same signals as the Army.  Wikipedia has a [brief article on the Army's signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_Hand_and_Arm_Signals), and the actual [Army Field Manual 21-60 - Visual Signs](http://www.enlistment.us/field-manuals/fm-21-60-visual-signs.shtml) is available online.

Then of course there are also less formal signals, like looking at somebody and pointing where you want them to go.